# tracking traffic source from cookie

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager

I want to establish lookup table macro depending on content of utm_z cookie.

For example if user have in utm_z cookie specific value (for example abc) my lookup table macro need to return specific value.

I made 1 party cookie variable returning value from utm_z cookie. This variable return for example '125233995.1441192396.4.2.utmcsr=aa|utmccn=cc|utmcmd=aa|utmctr=aaa|utmcct=bb

I can not use regular expresions in Lookup table macro.

Comment: wouldn't be option just to extract the content of the cookie with custom javascript and pass it to GMT?

Comment: I will do this in this way. I want to do this all in GTM (without changes in source).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without knowing which value you want to get, but you can use a custom javascript variable to extract the value via regex (e.g. something like `.*utmcsr(=.*?)\|.*` to get the utmcsr value) from your cookie variable and then pass the the variable with the extracted value to the lookup table.

So the first party cookie variable feeds into the custom javascript variable to extract the value which in turn feeds into the lookup table to return the  value you want.

Comment: It sounds very interesting. Could You send me all javascript which I need to put into custom js variable? I want to extract value from variable named "cookie_utmz". Cookie_utmz variable return values like _125233111.1441611234.11.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)_